# PySpark - How can I concatenate a string prefix of 0's to another string column based on a condition

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame where it looks like below

```
|string_code|prefix_string_code|
|1234       |001234            |
|123        |000123            |
|56789      |056789            |
```

Basically what I want is to add '0' as many as necessary so that the length of column `prefix_string_code` will be `6`.

What I have tried:

```
df.withColumn('prefix_string_code', when(length(col('string_code')) < 6, concat(lit('0' * (6 - length(col('string_code')))), col('string_code'))).otherwise(col('string_code')))
```

It did not work and instead produced the following:

```
|string_code|prefix_string_code|
|1234       |0.001234          |
|123        |0.000123          |
|56789      |0.056789          |
```

As you can see, if it's not in a decimal form, the code actually works. How do I do this properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use lpad function for this case

```
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F

>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([1234,123,56789,1234567])
>>> data = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(x))
>>> df=spark.createDataFrame(data,['string_code'])
>>> df.show()
+-----------+
|string_code|
+-----------+
|       1234|
|        123|
|      56789|
|    1234567|
+-----------+

>>> df.withColumn('prefix_string_code', F.when(F.length(df['string_code']) < 6 ,F.lpad(df['string_code'],6,'0')).otherwise(df['string_code'])).show()
+-----------+------------------+
|string_code|prefix_string_code|
+-----------+------------------+
|       1234|            001234|
|        123|            000123|
|      56789|            056789|
|    1234567|           1234567|
+-----------+------------------+
```